# Change window location href in subdomain iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have `a.example.com` and `b.example.com`;

When I put `b.example.com/foo` as iframe in `a.example.com`:

```
<iframe src='b.example.com/foo'></iframe>`
```

the `window.location.href` value accessible from `b.example.com` is ... `a.example.com/foo` (??)...

The problem is - I use an external library in `b.example.com/foo` that checks for `window.location.href` and it gets incorrect information.

For this scenario it appears to me that I should iframe `/foo` content on a completely different domain like:
`anotherexample.com/foo`, where the `window.location.href` would actually point to `anotherexample.com/foo`.

How can I force window object in iframe to actually use its subdomain instead of parent domain with added parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are using your script in the right subdomain? it seems your external library is accessing parent window using `window.parent.location`, here is a code to check if a page is loaded directly or within another page:

```
var is_loaded_directly = (window.location == window.parent.location);
```

Since this code works, something is wrong on your setup or library.

*Note:* maybe you can solve your issue by checking `document.location` instead of `window.location`.